# How to increase polygens in 3dsmax

Tags: modeling, 3dsmax

I am beginner in modelling. Can I increase object's polygen in 3dsmax? I want have smooth object that have not low polygens.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TurboSmooth modifier for this purpose, but before use it, you should make sure your model have enough edges and check if the edges are correct. for example, make sure your vertex not connect to odd number edges( like 3 or 5 edges ) always try to keep it in even numbers, 4 edges is standard, check image below : 
[image]

both of them used odd numbers ( 3 and 5 ) which is not correct.
try to add more edges to your model and Chamfer them if necessery, before applying turbosmooth or other smooth Modifier's.

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the polygon count of you model so many ways:

> 1. Use subdivide modifier.
> 2. Use the turbo smooth modifier.
> 3. Use tessellate modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can smooth it by adding a smooth or turbo smooth modifier, then convert it to polygon edit again - *or collapse the object class from modify tab* - this will reproduce polygon evenly all over the object faces.

Alternately you can select a ring or loop of faces then use the connect tool to add more resolution (polygons) to these selected polygons only

As for the fish model in your image, you can select one of the height faces, then from the polygon edit section in the modify panel on the right, click `ring` it'll select all the height faces all around the fish, then scroll down on the modify panel click on `connect` and set the number to add more resolution

**UPDATE:**
*Please take in consideration that there's nothing like infinite segments even spheres (balls) or cylinders in 3D just have a higher number of segments - usually 32+), you can double or triple it but not more, increasing objects segments for very high values can bring your computer down to its knees while modeling or rendering*

Answer (score 0):

New versions of 3dsmax (2015, 2016) have a new subdivision modifier called OpenSubDiv modifier.  This can be used to subdivide your model, and give it more polygons.  There is also the Turbosmooth, Meshsmooth, Tessellate, and Subdivide modifiers available.  All of these will add more geometry to your model, based on different algorithms.